# Windows 10 Pro Upgrade from 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems

I bought a Dell Laptop which had a Windows 10 Home OS pre-installed. Now I am thinking of Upgrading to Windows 10 Pro but I am not able to do it. Guys from service center are saying that I have an OEM key which can be only upgraded with a instore purchase of Windows 10 Pro. How do I install a 10 Pro on my laptop?

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://www.zdnet.com/article/going-pro-how-to-upgrade-windows-10-home-without-hassles/

Comment: So what have you tried that didn't work for you?

Comment: “How do I install a 10 Pro on my laptop?” - By purchasing a legitimate retail Windows 10 Professional license from a trustworthy resellers (Amazon, Newegg, Microsoft) and entering the product key.